# How to monitor particular column in database

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have an Oracle Database and I want to monitor a particular table/column in the DB . If the column value crosses threshold value I want to call my java application code to perform some operation LIKE EXAMPLE SCALE UP OR SHUTDOWN. How can I achieve this? Any pointers or help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set Serverout On
Declare
comm Varchar2(2000);
Begin
comm := OSCommand_Run('/home/jguy/runJavaApp.sh')--for calling commands
DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line(comm);
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm), they are designed to do stuff like this and I really wouldn't mess up it with Java in this case.

Comment: Thanks I was exploring this.But after trigger I want to invoke a java api like call a java method

Answer (score 1):

You can use [triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) (i this case an update trigger) that will execute a particular [function/stored procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28845/ch6.htm) on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

1. Trigger on the table, which will check column value upon each DML statement and if value crosses threshold.
2. As trigger may have some performance impact on table, you can create a scheduler job calling a stored procedure which will invoke on periodic basis (every min or anything you like) and then check the column value and call java app if it crosses threshold.

I prefer trigger but check the performance impact on the table.